# Finding third factor of polynomial $x^3 + px^2 + qx + r$ given that $x + a$ and $x + b$ are factors

Tags: polynomials

Hi can I get help solving this question please:

Two of the factors of $x^3+px^2+qx+r$  are $(x + a)$ and $(x + b)$. Find the third factor.

I've the answer: $( x-p+(a+b))$ in my year $10$ math book, but I do not know how to work it out.

Thank you

Comment: Hint: Vieta's relations would help. You need to decide if you want which one of $p, q, r$ In your expression for the third root though.

Comment: Change your textbook, the answer is $x+p-a-b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write the polynomial in factored form as:

$x^3+px^2+qx+r = (x + a) (x + b) (x + c)$  Equation (1).

The R.H.S can be expanded to obtain:

$x^3+px^2+qx+r= x^3+(a+b+c)x^2+(ab+ac+bc)x+abc$

Comparing the coefficient of $x^2$ in both sides, you see that:

$p=a+b+c$

It follows that:

$c=p-(a+b)$

so we can re-write the R.H.S of equation (1) as:

$x^3+px^2+qx+r = (x + a) (x + b) (x + p-(a+b))$

Comment: Thank you very much Emmad for editing and answering the question

Comment: You are welcome, I am glad it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use Euclidean division to write the polynomial $x^3+px^2+qx+r$ in the form $x^3+px^2+qx+r=A(x)(x+a)$, then apply again the Euclidean division to write the polynomial $A(x)$ in the form $A(x)=B(x)(x+b)$.

Then we have $$x^3+px^2+qx+r=B(x)(x+b)(x+a)$$

$B(x)$ is the third factor that we are looking for.

**EDIT:**

Are you familiar with the division of polynomials?

From the division of $x^3+px^2+qx+r$ and $x+a$ we get $$x^3+px^2+qx+r=(x+a)(x^2+(p-a)x+(q-ap+a^2))+(-a^3+a^2p-aq+r)$ Since $x+a$ is a factor of the polynomial we have that $-a$ is a root of the polynomial , so $-a^3+a^2p-aq+r=0$.

So we have $$x^3+px^2+qx+r=(x+a)(x^2+(p-a)x+(q-ap+a^2))$$

Then from the division of $x^2+(p-a)x+(q-ap+a^2)$ and $x+b$ we get $$x^2+(p-a)x+(q-ap+a^2)=(x+b)(x+(p-a-b))$$ So $(x+(p-a-b))$$ is the third factor.

Comment: i've got the answer:  ( x-p+(a+b))  in my year 10 math book, but I do not know how to work it out

Comment: @Gehan: Mary Star just gave you the answer.

Comment: Division of polynomials is completely useless here... Call the last fact $(x+c)$, expand $(x+a)(x+b)(x+c) = x^3 + px^2+qx+r$, and you get the answer.